# how do I find the actual logistic regression model in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression

### I used logistic regression with python and got an accuracy score of 95%, how do I get this equation so that I can actually implement it?

**I wrote:**

```
model = LogisticRegression()
model.fit(train_X,train_y)
prediction=model.predict(test_X)
print('Accuracy:', "\n", '%',metrics.accuracy_score(prediction,test_y) * 100)
```

**and my output was:**
Accuracy: 
%95.5555555556

Comment: A little more context will help: sklearn? Or something else? What do you want to implement? Or do you want to use the trained classifer on some test data?

Comment: I just want to find the equation that it used to get the 95% accuracy. For example, using the iris data set that shows pedal/sepal length, I want to be able to use the formula to create a form that people can enter their data and it will predict it

Comment: Then use `model.predict` on some other data?  It has the model inside - which David's answers tells you how to get the details of. You don't need to re-code it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `model` object has an attribute called `coef_` where the coefficients of the model are stored. In addition, the attribute `intercept_` gives the intercept of the model.

Comment: Im sorry if this is a stupid question, but is there a way to write something along the lines of:

    print(coef_)
    print(intercept_)?

Comment: Yes, `print(model.coef_)` and `print(model.intercept_)` should work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you're using SkLearn. But what do you mean by implement it? Are you looking to write it into a separate language, or use a different library (i.e. TensorFlow)?

If you just want to keep the model and use it in a python program later, you can save and load it with Pickle.